# Google Assistant API usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-assistant-sdk

Will the use of Google Assistant API, share the data with google.We have a ITSM use case where enterprise users will be interacting with assistant.
Can we have a option of not sharing that info/data to google of whatever has been conversed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will share the data with Google. You are literally sending them the data.

Another thing to note.

> "Warning: The Google Assistant SDK is for non-commercial use only."

Can be found on https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/support